# new relic with multiple apps and multiple accounts in one server

Tags: nginx, php, newrelic

I have a server (nginx + php-fpm) running 3 sites each one must be reported in a separate new relic account.

I have an only php-fpm config and 3 server config settings into /etc/nginx/conf.d

I set into each nginx server config file the new relic license and new relic app name but it only takes the license set in newrelic.ini.

How could I to set I don't know, per ini (server config file) or whatever to new relic make reports of each site to each account associated with?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can separate sites into different New Relic accounts one of two ways:

1) You can setup virtual hosts in nginx, and add different New Relic license keys to each virtual host. There is an example using Apache on the New Relic [docs site](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/php-agent/features/multiple-accounts#vhost).

2) You can call `newrelic_set_appname()` via the API and change the account during the beginning of the transaction.

For example: `newrelic_set_appname("APP NAME",  "NEW RELIC LICENSE KEY");`

There is more information on using multiple accounts [here](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/php-agent/features/multiple-accounts).

Comment: yes, what I was failing due for unkonwn about nginx config files is that I was setting multiple `fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE` declarations and must exists only one.

Answer (score 0):

First off, the preferred way to start New Relic now is to not use daemon mode for the proxy daemon. Simple remove its script from init.

Secondly, you really want to use different php-fpm pools. The configuration for apache mentioned in the other answer works, because mod php is integrated in apache. Nginx uses php-fpm and its generally better to rub different applications from different pools, so you can tune settings properly. The license for New Relic is one of those things, you can then set in the pool configuration.